# Scaling an object inside another scaled object

Tags: geometry

I have an object contained in another object. Imagine a little circle in a rectangle.I want to know the relative position of the circle related to the rectangle given the absolute position of the circle.

When the rectangle is in the middle, it's simple, the absolute and relative positions are the same. For all the cases, I just have to subtract the position of the rectangle from the absolute position and I get the relative position.

The problem I have is when I scale both objects at the same time. I tried dividing the positions with the scale factor with no luck. How can I get the relative position when both objects are scaled?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By "relative position", do you mean the displacement between the center of the circle and the center of the rectangle?

Comment: Is the scaling of the two being done relative to a common point?

Comment: @Kajelsd Yes.@amd No, they are relative to each center

Comment: If each object is scaled relative to its own center, then the two centers remain fixed, so there’s nothing to recompute.

Comment: @amd But the circle is contained by the rectangle. When the rectangle is scaled relative to its own center, the circle is also going to be scaled and it's going to move. This scaling of the circle is independent of its own scaling relative to its center. So yes, the circle is scaled twice, one relative to its center and one relative to the rectangle center.

Comment: You’re going to have to describe these transformations more precisely for someone to answer you. A picture or two would help a lot.